# Why ctrl in my directive is null?

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel, angular-directive

I have a directive like this but why the argument ***ctrl*** is *null*?

**Markup:**

```
<test ng-name="htest" ng-family="hfamily" ></test>
```

**Directive:**

```
 var tmp = "<input   type='text' ng-model='htest' >";

return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: tmp,
    require: "^?ngModel",
    scope: {
        name: "=ngName",
        family:"=ngFamily"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", ctrl);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to insert ng-model='htest' in the first html tag like

```
<test ng-name="htest" ng-family="hfamily" ng-model='htest'></test>
```